# Why are there chinese character in my R markdown file?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

Have a look at the attached picture, which comes from an RStudio notebook...

[image]

After I render this into an HTML file, I get the following:

[image]

Why do the "?" characters become "chinese?" characters?
Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What's your `Sys.getlocale()` in the notebook?

Comment: `"LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"`